# Using modelica function as input to external "C" function

Tags: c, function, external, modelica, dymola

I am trying to call an external C function in modelica with a function as an argument.
So the C function needs to take a modelica "function" as input.  Is it possible to do that in modelica ?

For example :

```
function foo

  input Function fun;
  output Real bar ;

  external "C" bar = myCFunction(fun) annotations(...);

end foo;

function Function
  input Real u;
  output Real y;
algorithm
   y := u*2;
end Function;
```

When I use the "check" option, I get some error stating fun is undeclared which I don't if I do not use a function as input.
I looked online and in the use manual of dymola but I haven't found an example stating it was possible, nor impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that's possible. You can check the [Modelica Specification](https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch12.html#external-function-interface) about allowed input types to external functions.

Comment: I checked this page before posting and indeed I did not find anything about functions. I hoped that maybe it was still possible somehow.

Comment: Note that function inputs in Modelica are a bit generalized compared to C, and is actually a closure - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming) - That means it is slightly more complicated - but Dymola already handles it internally when generating C-code for the internal functions. However, that handling isn't standarized (yet).